# Intellij hotkey / shortcut that will transform text into two xml / html elements e.g. aaaaa into <aaaaa></aaaaa>

Tags: intellij-idea, hotkeys

I accidentally pressed some buttons and magically

`aaaaa` was transformed into `<aaaaa></aaaaa>` while editing a PHP file. I cannot reproduce the hotkey though.

Is there a way to find this specific hotkey? pretty usefull imho

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you're editing something xml-ish then you can simply press tab and IntelliJ will turn the previous word into a tag as you describe.

In your example, type `aaaaa`<kbd>tab</kbd> and you'll get `<aaaaa></aaaaa>` as a result.

AFAIK: this works in html, xml, and jsp, but may also work in other places